# How do I use %empty correctly?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison

I'm new to bison/fex and I am trying to recognize patterns of 1-3 words of input.

My .l recognizes WORD as any series of lowercase characters, treats % and $ characters as tokens of their own ascii value, ignores whitespace, and recognizes everything else as an ERR token.

```
MISC    [\%\$]

%%

[a-z]+ { yylval.WORD = yytext; return WORD; }

[ \t\r\n]+  {} //ignore whitespace

{MISC}  return (int) yytext[0];

. return ERR; //unrecognized input
```

My .y tries to recognize sequences of 1-3 WORDS separated by characters % and $. I want it so that even if I input just 1 WORD, I still get a complete statement. I don't include any rules for the ERR token to invoke a syntax error in the parser when an unrecognize character is received as input.

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex();
    void yyerror(char* s){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
    };
%}

%define api.value.type union 

%token <char*> WORD
%nterm <char*> word1 word2 word3
%token ERR

%%

statement: word1 word2 word3 { printf("%s, %s, %s\n", $1, $2, $3); return 0; }
         ;

word1: WORD { $$ = $1; }
      ;

word2: %empty { $$ = "nothing"; }
      | '%' WORD { $$ = $2; }
      ;

word3: %empty { $$ = "nothing";}
      | '$' WORD { $$ = $2; }
      ;

%%
```

My main.c loops on yyparse(). Ideally I'm trying to parse only 1 line of input per iteration.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int yyparse();
int yylex();
extern FILE* yyin;
extern void yyrestart();

int main() {
    while(1) {
        printf("input: ");
        if (yyparse() == 0) {
            printf("success\n");
        };
        yyrestart(yyin);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting adverse output, and I can't explain what's causing it:

- In: word word -> Out: word word, nothing, nothing
- In: word word word -> Out: word word, nothing, nothing
- In: word % word $ word -> Out: word % word $ word, word $ word, word

Additionally, if I input only 1 WORD, my command line hangs until it receives additional input. This additional input could be anything. Even characters that would normally be recognized as an ERR token and invoke a syntax error somehow get by.

- In: word. -> Out: word., nothing, nothing

I want my parser to be able to run even if I give it only 1 word of input. I thought that with the inclusion of %empty for subrules word2 and word3 I would get this behavior, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are  ignoring newline characters so there is no way your parser can guess that a single word is all you are going to type. Naturally it waits for you to type more.

Comment: Another standard problem is `yylval = yytext;`. That's never correct. You must make a copy of the token string if you want it to survive longer than the scanner action (for example, in order to return it to the parser.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for the advice on yytext, I used strdup and it fixed all my errors regarding yylval! I stopped ignoring \n so that it's returned as an ERR token, but functionally nothing changed (command line still hangs if I only provide 1 word of input). I would have expected at least a syntax error to be invoked.

Comment: `.` doesn't match newline, so just removing `\n` from the ignored character list doesn't cause the parser to do anything with `\n`. (Actually, it echoes it to standard output, which is (f)lex's default action. I usually add `%option nodefault` to suppress the default action, which means that flex will warn me if my patterns miss some character.

Comment: More accurately, I use `%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault`, which allows me to compile and link with `-Wall` (always a good idea) and without `-lfl`.

Comment: If you want to read line by line, you could get your scanner to return `\n` when it sees one, and the add a start symbol to your parser `program: %empty | program statement '\n' | program '\n' | program error '\n' { yyerrok; }`

Comment: I added a NEWLINE token that recognizes \n to my parser rules and I see what you mean. Thanks a lot for the tips! I got my program (mostly) working and I'll definitely be trying these suggestions out.